# Vba ms-access Loop Recordset Print info to textbox

Tags: vba, loops, textbox, recordset

I made a sub that deletes records in a table via a recordset.
I would like to print the key of the record that is deleted to a textbox on a form.
So after each delete the key has to be added to the textbox on the form.

Below you can find the code, that doesn't print anything to the form.

I'm missing something.

```
Public Sub Erase()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenDynaset) 'dynaset voor linked tables
  
    If rs1.EOF Then Exit Sub

    Do Until rs1.EOF
        If rs1!Icoon = "del" Then
            Debug.Print "Debug Print :" & rs1(0).Value
            strOutput = "Ent: " & rs1(0).Value & vbCrLf
            On Error Resume Next
            rs1.Delete
            txtOutput.value = strOutput
            i = DoEvents
        End If
        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot the form ... txtOutput.value = strOutput should be: 
[Forms]![Frm_Main]![txtOutput] = strOutput

Comment: Especially if you are deleting multiple rows, have you stepped through your code to make sure each row is deleted and displayed on the form? (It might be going so fast you don't see them all.) Also, why are you disabling errors in your loop (and not re-enabling them)?

Comment: Display on the form: I know, but I don't know how to solve it.
Errors: I have locking issues with some records in the database.  I haven't yet figured out how to do this in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot the form ... txtOutput.value = strOutput should be: [Forms]![Frm_Main]![txtOutput] = strOutput